# Localhost : 404 not found

Tags: xampp, localhost

I am using XAMPP. and internal server of Django.
When I browse to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, It shows 
`Not Found . HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.`

It sometimes works fine and other times pops up the error.

Moreover, when I browse to my project url, ie `127.0.0.1:8000/cc` , the project url works fine.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 28):

You need to add the port number to every address you type in your browser when you have changed the default port from port 80.

For example: localhost:8000/cc .

A little edition here is that it should be **8080** in place of 8000. 
For example - 
http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/

Comment: A tiny detail but easily forgotten! Keen eye you have. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and here is how it worked for me :

1) Open XAMPP control panel.

2)On the right top corner go to **config** > **Service and Port setting**
and change the port (I did 81 from 80).

3)Open config in Apache just right(next) to Apache admin Option and click on that and select first one (httpd.conf) it will open in the notepad.

4) There you find port listen 80 and replace it with 81 in all place and save the file.

5) Now restart Apache and MYSql

6) Now type following in Browser : 
http://localhost:81/phpmyadmin/

I hope this works.

Answer (score 2):

Type in "netstat -ano" into your command line. I saw that it was showing something for Local Address port 0.0.0.0:80.

My issue was because I had SQL Server Reporting Services on Port 80. So I followed these instructions and changed the port # from 80 to 81:

http://seankilleen.com/2012/11/how-to-stop-sql-server-reporting-services-from-using-port-80-on-your-server-field-notes/

Here is a picture of my command line after I changed the port number for SQL Server Reporting Services:

[image]

If you are still having the same issue, read this forum:

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,66196,66233#REPLY

Answer (score 2):

Many frameworks like `Laravel` , `Django` ,... run local web server that work on another port except 80.For example port `8000` is the most commen port that these local web servers use.

So when you run web servers that frameworks build them and type `localhost:8000` it works well.But web server that `xampp(apache)` runs it has another port.In default it has `80` that it does not need to type it in url.And if you change port you should mention it in url.

**In brief:**web server in framework is different from web server in xampp . Check the port of each server and mention it in url when you use them.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is still listening on port 80, check the permission on the DocumentRoot folder and if DirectoryIndex file existed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to stop that service running on this port .check service running on specific port by "netstat -ano".then in window search type services.exe and search that process and stop that process .to change port of that process check this
http://seankilleen.com/2012/11/how-to-stop-sql-server-reporting-services-from-using-port-80-on-your-server-field-notes/

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your web routes most likely there is nothing pointing to the default path  in your routes `//default path or route Route::get('/', [ PagesController::class,'index']);` in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a 404 Error in PHP or you are not able to see PHPMyAdmin,
it might be you have changed your default port.
For instance, I have changed from port 80 to 8081. So after changing the port, you have to just type http://localhost:8081 in your browser.

eg: `localhost:yourPortName/`
phpmyadmin Page - `http://localhost:8081/phpmyadmin/`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open XAMPP control panel.

2)On the right top corner go to **config > Service and Port** setting and change the port. Under the Apache tab , change **main port to 8080 and SSL port to 4433** and click save.

[screenshot of Service and Port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFfmD.jpg)

3) **Change the Default Port Settings of the httpd.conf File**

- Open config in Apache just right(next) to Apache admin Option and
  click on that and select the first one (httpd.conf) it will open in
  the notepad.
- Locate 80( to get started, press Ctrl + F, then enter    “80” in the
  search field.)
- Modify the following lines :
  Port 80 to    Port    8080
  Listen 80 to Listen 8080
  servername localhost:80  to  servername    localhost:8080

4) **Update the Default Port Settings in the http-ssl.conf File**

- Open config in Apache just right(next) to Apache admin Option and
  click on that and select the first one (http-ssl.conf) it will open
  in the notepad.
- Locate 443( to get started, press Ctrl + F, then    enter “443” in
  the search field.)
- Modify the following sentences:

  ```
       Listen 443   => Listen 4433
       <VirtualHost _default_:443>   =>  <VirtualHost _default_:4433>
       ServerName www.example.com:443   => ServerName www.example.com:4433
  ```

5. Now restart Apache and MYSql
6. Now type following in Browser : http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/
   Note: you can use any other port

Answer (score -1):

open D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs"
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride FileInfo
         Require all granted

Restart Apache server

and then refresh your given url

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it was just a VPN problem.

I was working in my companies network (via VPN).
After switching to private network, the problem disappeared!